# office 365 word document manipulation

Tags: javascript

Using the js add-in for the browser-only context in office 365, is it possible ,( and importantly realistic ) to:

- show/hide sections in a word document
- delete/copy/paste sections in a word document
- protect/unprotect the word document?
- simulate fill-in fields over a protected backdrop?

if not via the js api  (ie the Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync typ ebof approach) , can I edit an underlying OOXML format and refresh browser doc from this source?

In summary: can I do what I could do in c# / VBA in the browser-only environment?